# How do I perform Visual search using Android API?

Tags: android, search

I want to use the Camera Image to get the google search results. I could not find a way to do that using Android API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want Google Goggles. It's an application that you should be able to use via an Intent. Except that apparently Google doesn't provide a way to call it via an Intent. If Google did it I'm sure you could to, but it is probably rather difficult.